# Recursion function, random choices with probability from list

Tags: python, recursion, random

I need to make a simulator which makes, for the input list, a list (elements are random choices from rdm_lst) of lists.
I have:

```
lst = ["a", "a", "a"]
rdm_lst = ["a", "b", "c"]

def simulator(lst, rdm_lst):
    sim = []
    for i in lst:
        if i == "a":
            sim.append(np.random.choice(rdm_lst, size=1, p=[0.6, 0.2, 0.2]).tolist()[0])
        elif i == "b":
            sim.append(np.random.choice(rdm_lst, size=1, p=[0.2, 0.6, 0.2]).tolist()[0])
        elif i == "c":
            sim.append(np.random.choice(rdm_lst, size=1, p=[0.2, 0.2, 0.6]).tolist()[0])
    return sim

simulator(rdm_lst)
```

The output is one list, the problem I have is, that I do not know how to repete this function k time, having as a result list of lists, where the input of a simulator() will be the previous list, not the first one.
I tried, put:

```
return simulator(sim)
```

instead:

```
return sim
```

bun an error occurs.
Kindly help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you are trying to implement a [Markov chain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov_chain).

You could simplify a bit your code by defining your transitions with a `dict` (since your states are labeled, and you are currently using `numpy` -- in this case, a Pandas DataFrame would be more intuitive, but this will do).

```py
Px = {
    'a': np.array([0.6, 0.2, 0.2]),
    'b': np.array([0.2, 0.6, 0.2]),
    'c': np.array([0.2, 0.2, 0.6]),
}

def simulator(xs, Px, k=1):
    labels = list(Px)
    return [
        xs := [np.random.choice(labels, p=Px[x]) for x in xs]
        for _ in range(k)
    ]
```

##### Example

```py
np.random.seed(0)
>>> simulator(['a', 'b', 'c'], Px, k=10)
[['a', 'b', 'c'],
 ['a', 'b', 'c'],
 ['a', 'c', 'c'],
 ['a', 'c', 'c'],
 ['a', 'c', 'a'],
 ['a', 'a', 'c'],
 ['b', 'c', 'c'],
 ['b', 'c', 'c'],
 ['a', 'c', 'a'],
 ['c', 'c', 'a']]
```

##### Explanation

Given `xs` a list of initial states, we make a new list of states with the list comprehension: `[np.random.choice(labels, p=Px[x]) for x in xs]`. We then assign this back to `xs` (with the ["walrus operator"](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.8.html#assignment-expressions)), and iterate `k` times.

##### Fun stuff

The more usual definition of a finite state Markov chain is with the transition matrix:

```py
P = np.c_[list(Px.values())]
>>> P
array([[0.6, 0.2, 0.2],
       [0.2, 0.6, 0.2],
       [0.2, 0.2, 0.6]])
```

(And you can map the labels separately, or use `pandas` with labels as index and columns).

What is the expected state distribution after two transitions given an initial state `(1,0,0)` (`'a'`)?

```py
>>> np.array((1,0,0)) @ P @ P
array([0.44, 0.28, 0.28])
```

What is the terminal expected state distribution given an initial state `(1,0,0)`?

```py
# approximation of v @ P^inf
>>> np.array((1,0,0)) @ np.linalg.matrix_power(P, int(10**9))
array([0.33333334, 0.33333334, 0.33333334])
```

More precisely: what is the stationary distribution (a state distribution such that it is unchanged by transition `P`)?

```py
w, v = np.linalg.eig(P.T)  # left eigen system
k = np.argmax(w)
assert np.allclose(w[k], 1), 'no stationary state!'
e = v[:, k]
e /= e.sum()
>>> e
array([0.33333333, 0.33333333, 0.33333333])

>>> e @ P
array([0.33333333, 0.33333333, 0.33333333])
```

So, the expected distribution after a large number of transitions is 1/3 for each state, regardless of the initial state (because all states are reachable from any initial state).